# how use bindingredirect attribute to redirect to current version of assembly

Tags: .net

I want to use bindingredirect attribute to redirect old version of assembly to latest release version, Is it possible or I have to change newversion value each time when I make a new release?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460271/how-to-use-assembly-binding-redirection-to-ignore-revision-and-build-numbers).